# Im not able to view Project structure in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-4.0

In this Image i'm not able to view my Project in android plese help me
[android studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKcZa.jpg)

[modules image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlmVI.jpg)

**EDIT** - hey i got the answer
i have deleted all modules and .iml files an restarted the studio it worked

Comment: How does project structure look like in a folder? Are you sure no files are missing?

Comment: in projectview in android option , i'm able to see only gradle scripts and my projects is not loading , i'm not able to find which file im missing

Comment: * How does the project structure look like in a folder? Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: sure i'll make a post

Comment: please check the screenshot above

Comment: Please, show screenshot of "File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules" in Android Studio.

Comment: please check above i have updated

Comment: I guess your project is not buiilding. Try closing studio remove your project from Recent and open again using Settings.gradle.

Comment: no i have tried that many times, and i have uninstall the studio and re-install the studio  by fresh way but it is showing same problem

Comment: Select "projects" from dropdown instead of "android" that would make project appearance.

Comment: https://ibb.co/KVGhKjS

Answer (score 0):

Just try restarting android studio. If that does not work, try rebooting pc and if that too does not work then try uninstalling Android studio and install it again. This happened to me once and I just restarted android studio and the project view was back.